# Soaring revenues have papered over years

Tags: word-usage

What does "paper" mean here?  Does it mean "to fold, enclose, or wrap in paper"?

> New York Times tweeted:
> Today’s Great Read:

> Despite being the richest soccer club in the world, Barcelona has been walking a financial tightrope. **Soaring revenues have papered over years** of impulsive management and imprudent contracts. But as the pandemic hit, the math changed.

Answer (score 5):

It's "papered over", as in the phrase "papered over the cracks".

It means you're covering something up superficially, without actually sorting out the root cause. Like putting wallpaper on a wall where the plaster has cracked.

The journalist is saying that the "impulsive management and imprudent contracts" really needed to be fixed, but the large revenues meant they could cover up the problems, without actually dealing with them.